# How to use key function in xslt v2.0.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I don't know how will I put the correct title. I am using a key function for grouping the elements. I need to create `<Acct>` tag for every unique value of BnkAcct/BBANID and XSeq/Seq. However, I can't get the certain value of an element if it is within another element. This is my XML file:

```
<XMLFile>
<Hdr>
    <DctID>
        <ID>2017-02-20ZTenantID</ID>
    </DctID>
    <Dscpt>Slovenska</Dscpt>
</Hdr>
<Acct>
    <LNo>1</LNo>
    <XSeq>
        <Seq>111</Seq>
    </XSeq>
    <Prd>
        <SDT>21.03.2016</SDT>
        <EDT>21.03.2016</EDT>
    </Prd>
    <BnkAcct>
        <BBANID>AAA111</BBANID>
    </BnkAcct>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>4.42</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>1</No>
            <Amt>122.43</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
</Acct>
<Acct>
    <LNo>1</LNo>
    <XSeq>
        <Seq>444</Seq>
    </XSeq>
    <Prd>
        <SDT>21.06.2016</SDT>
        <EDT>21.06.2016</EDT>
    </Prd>
    <BnkAcct>
        <BBANID>DDD444</BBANID>
    </BnkAcct>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>94.32</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>4</No>
            <Amt>852.11</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
</Acct>
<Acct>
        <LNo>1</LNo>
    <XSeq>
        <Seq>444</Seq>
    </XSeq>
    <Prd>
        <SDT>21.06.1999</SDT>
        <EDT>21.06.2001</EDT>
    </Prd>
    <BnkAcct>
        <BBANID>DDD444</BBANID>
    </BnkAcct>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>2332.353</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>5</No>
            <Amt>23422.31</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
</Acct>
</XMLFile>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="Header2" match="Acct" use="concat(BBANID, '|', Seq)"/>
<xsl:template match="/XMLFile">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Hdr"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Acct[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Header2', concat(BBANID, '|', Seq))[1])]" mode="Header2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Acct" mode="Header2">
    <BankStatementAccount>
        <xsl:copy-of select="LNo|Seq|Prd|ID"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Header2', concat(BBANID, '|', Seq))"/>
    </BankStatementAccount>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Acct">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Entry"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<XMLFile>
<Hdr>
    <DctID>
        <ID>2017-02-20ZTenantID</ID>
    </DctID>
    <Dscpt>Slovenska</Dscpt>
</Hdr>
<Acct>
    <LNo>1</LNo>
    <XSeq>
        <Seq>111</Seq>
    </XSeq>
    <Prd>
        <SDT>21.03.2016</SDT>
        <EDT>21.03.2016</EDT>
    </Prd>
    <BnkAcct>
        <BBANID>AAA111</BBANID>
    </BnkAcct>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>4.42</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>1</No>
            <Amt>122.43</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
</Acct>
<Acct>
    <LNo>1</LNo>
    <XSeq>
        <Seq>444</Seq>
    </XSeq>
    <Prd>
        <SDT>21.06.2016</SDT>
        <EDT>21.06.2016</EDT>
    </Prd>
    <BnkAcct>
        <BBANID>DDD444</BBANID>
    </BnkAcct>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>94.32</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>4</No>
            <Amt>852.11</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Amt>2332.353</Amt>
        <Dtl>
            <No>5</No>
            <Amt>23422.31</Amt>
        </Dtl>
    </Entry>
</Acct>
</XMLFile>
```

The XSLT is not working maybe because of the use attributes I used? The BBANID is from the `<BnkAcct>` and Seq is from `<XSeq>`. How will I use the specific elements in the use attribute if it is within the another element?

By the way, the XSLT is working if I removed the `<BnkAcct>` tag and `<XSeq>` tag but this is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, why aren't you grouping with the `xsl:for-each-group` command?

Comment: @michael.hor247k: ohh!I'm sorry, I don't know. I'm just copying the ideas that I've seen in te web.

Answer (score 0):

The subject talks about XSLT 2 but the code has version `1.0`. As for the `key` problem, with the `<xsl:key name="Header2" match="Acct" use="concat(BBANID, '|', Seq)"/>` I think you want `<xsl:key name="Header2" match="Acct" use="concat(.//BBANID, '|', .//Seq)"/>` or `<xsl:key name="Header2" match="Acct" use="concat(BnkAcct/BBANID, '|', XSeq/Seq)"/>`, to match the input XML.